# How do I load Spring bean definitions from XML file specified in a properties file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-java-config

I specified name of XML file with Spring bean definitions in a properties file:

myConfigurationFile=mySpringConfigurationFile1.xml

How do I tell Spring to load those bean definitions into Spring context defined by JavaConfig?
It seems that I need an equivalent of @ImportResource, called programmatically from JavaConfig.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can use FileSystemXmlApplicationContext or ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to achieve this.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s07.html

Comment: This is better than my answer, better way round :)

Comment: How would I merge the context loaded from the XML file with the context loaded from JavaConfig?

Comment: you can add this line <context:component-scan base-package="" /> . to your mySpringConfigurationFile1.xml. however you need to to point the base-package to the location where your java classes annotated with spring annotations.